# Does Facebook generate the same "offline_access" Access Token for the same user each time they authenticate?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm building a web application and I'm using OAuth to provide Facebook authentication. I've successfully generated an access_token and each time the user logs out/back in, I match their access_token to find their account. This works very well.

In addition, I'm building a Windows Phone 7 companion app. I've got the same process for authentication, using the Facebook SDK, but the access_token that is returned is different. This means I cannot match the account.

Since the logout/login to my web application appears to generate the same access_token repeatedly, I'm confused as to why the mobile app generates a different access token.

Can anyone tell me if the behaviour I'm expecting is correct? I've scoured the Facebook documentation, but can't find anything relevant. Maybe OAuth isn't the correct thing to do here.

Comment: With what permissions are you asking for? I believe if you ask for "offline_access", they should be the same. Also, are you using the same app_id/app_secret in your web app and your windows phone 7 app? If not, you'll receive a different auth_token

Comment: Asking for "offline_access" only and I am using the same app_id & secret in both places. I really just wanted to confirm I should be seeing the same access_token. There is clearly a bug in my code somewhere if that's the case.

Comment: I've triple checked my code. The WP7 emulator is getting the same access_token consistently, but it's different from the one generated by the web login. This is not ideal!

Comment: Are you using the same methods for authenticating at FB? Graph vs. RESTful???

Comment: I'm using the Facebook C# SDK's FacebookOAuthClient class. The code I use on the Web and WP7 is almost identical, except the "display" paramter in the WP7 app is set to "wap" as I was experiencing issues with JavaScript in the WP7 Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time I logged in, the code would return a different access_code value. I needed to add a new field called "response_type" with a value of "code". This then redirected me to the login page and responded with the correct token, which I then exchanged for an access code.

To generate the URL, this was the code:

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthClient client = new Facebook.FacebookOAuthClient();
client.AppId = "285539721457932";
client.AppSecret = "65233641cf71e6fa9fef5ecd7d802ebf";
client.RedirectUri = new Uri("http://www.imaybelate.com/Account/FacebookCallback");

url = client.GetLoginUrl(new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    { "display", "wap" },
    { "response_type", "code" },
    { "permissions","offline_access"}
}).ToString();
```

Comment: To improve the quality of this post please include what the error was and how you fixed it so that future users can solve similar problems.

Comment: Sorry. I was being lazy. I've dug the code out of Git and updated the answer.

Comment: Good to see, No hard feelings but your post showed up in the low quality posts section of the review queue.

Comment: None at all! Thanks for making me answer it correctly. I get annoyed when I see answer like that from others :)